# how to combine multiple rows into one row in table in oracle and store result in other table

Tags: oracle

sample data: table consists of 96000 rows and i want to combine them into 16000 rows

row 1:1255467861  40825825                        IDF+0149502016010615210300000396000026+0000651+                    00000000000000+|

row 2:000000000+0000000+0000000+000000677+02 YY       0444410100000     00    0001000000054+10001EB4200002+00000+0000052+0000000+0000000+|

row 3:00000    00000+00000+0000000+0000000+0000000+00000    00000+00000+0000000+0000000+0000000+00000    00000+00000+0000000+0000000+|

row 4:0000000+00000    00000+00000+0000000+0000000+0000000+00       004                         1       000000000000      0000000000   M5|

row 5:      00000000                                     +00000000000000000000000000000000000000+00000000001011 Y 000000000+|

row 6:0000000+0000000+0000000+AB0002210000000000FIABMM81       15067195  0000000000009403228870|

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!  Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know what the criteria (column1, column2 in the example) for grouping your rows is, I suggest you to use  [aggregate functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035) functions such as SUM(), MAX(), and COUNT() to aggregate data, Group by the criteria, and insert into the target table.

**E.G.**

```
insert into my_target_table
Select column1, column2, sum(column3), max(column4), count(1) as column5
from my_source_table
group by column_1, column2
```

Comment: my requirement is not fullfilled actually i want these six rows as one row in my table and i have only one column in my table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "row 1, row 2, row 3" has some meaning, you must have another column somewhere that shows the order. In my setup below, I assume you have an "id" (not necessarily consecutive numbers starting from 1; it can be number, or it can be date, etc. - for illustration I use some random numbers, they can also be fractional, or negative etc. - I build "row numbers" form that). If you don't have ANY kind of ordering, in the "order by" clause for the row_number() function you can simply "order by 1". However, I assume you also want to capture the minimum value of the "id" from each group of six (again, the id may be a date or timestamp or whatever).

The strategy is to create "row numbers". It works better if everything starts from 0, so I subtract 1 from the row_number() values. Then group by trunc(rn/6) and order by mod(rn, 6).

To concatenate the strings use listagg. I assume you wanted the strings concatenated with NO separator between them; if you do want them separated, for example, by #, then change the second argument to listagg from '' to '#'.

**Query** (including setup data, I shortened the input strings and I added a few more to show how everything works):

```
with test_data(id, input_str) as (
        select  1, '12554861 40825825 IDF+0140000000+|'    from dual union all
        select  2, '0000000+00052+0000000+0000000+|'       from dual union all
        select  4, '00000 000+00000+0+00000+000+0000000+|' from dual union all
        select  9, '00000+0000000+000000000000 M5|'        from dual union all
        select 14, '000000 +000000000011 Y 000000000+|'    from dual union all
        select 23, '000000IABMM81 15067195 0000003228870|' from dual union all
        select 31, '125508825 IDF+0143333300000+|'         from dual union all
        select 32, '0000+052+0000AXZC000+0000000+|'        from dual union all
        select 37, '000MMDOQ000+0+00000+0000000+0000000+|' from dual union all
        select 45, '000000 +00000000001011 Y 000000000+|'  from dual union all
        select 46, '00000+0000FIAB1 15067195 000CCV70|'    from dual
     ),
     has_rn (id, input_str, rn) as (
        select id, input_str, row_number() over (order by id) - 1
        from   test_data
     )
select   min(id) as id, 
         listagg(input_str, '') within group (order by mod(rn, 6)) as output_str
from     has_rn
group by trunc(rn/6);
```

**Output** (using the sample inputs in the test_data cte):

```
ID OUTPUT_STR
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 12554861 40825825 IDF+0140000000+|0000000+00052+0000000+0000000+|00000 000+00000+0+00000+000+0000000+|00000+0000000+000000000000 M5|000000 +000000000011 Y 000000000+|000000IABMM81 15067195 0000003228870|
31 125508825 IDF+0143333300000+|0000+052+0000AXZC000+0000000+|000MMDOQ000+0+00000+0000000+0000000+|000000 +00000000001011 Y 000000000+|00000+0000FIAB1 15067195 000CCV70|
```